# Relative position of Buttons in different devices

Tags: android

[image]I have a problem in relation to the relative location of Buttons in different devices. I have done a short application to show it. The Button, in relation to a red point, behaves as desire when dealing with wide measures (coordinate x). However, I don’t know why the same Button is progressively scrolling down from the red point (coordinate y) as I choose a smaller device. I choose the right size of the image for the different devices and for both, wide and height, I also choose the relative measure of the screen:
    rel_btn.width = 4*width/100;
    rel_btn.height = 7*height/100;

I show you the code and the resulting screen of the xlarge screen in case someone can help me:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //width and height of the screen
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (windowManager != null) {
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    }
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.test); // id del XML
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rel_btn.width = 4*width/100; rel_btn.height = 7*height/100;
        // x, y of the BUTTON
        rel_btn.leftMargin = 15*width/100; rel_btn.topMargin = 66*height/100;
        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
        btnTag.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        btnTag.setId(0); // writes the ID
        btnTag.setOnClickListener(prueba);
        layout.addView(btnTag);
}

private View.OnClickListener prueba = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //width of the screen
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (windowManager != null) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        }
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        Button button = (Button) view;
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        drawable.setStroke(Math.round((float) (0.6*width/100)), Color.BLUE);
        drawable.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
};
```

}
[image]

Comment: In a relative layout shouldn't the button be positioned relative to other views?

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: I don't see any positioning of the button on the layouot, you only defined a width and a height. In any cas you should have some rule to align to the parent. See the xml in this link to get an idea: https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/

Comment: I thought that (rel_btn.width = 4*width/100; rel_btn.height = 7*height/100;) were positions of the button on the layout and I think they were relative, too, since they take width and height into account. Don’t you think so? Your link is for different purposes.

Comment: I am not going to argue with you. Check the docs. RelativeLayout is relative becase the position of the views is set in relation to other views. Nothing to do with the calculation you did for width and height. you can do that for a LinearLayout and it would still work.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't my intention to argue with you. I'll take your suggestion into account tomorrow again and I'll study it once more.